# Does grails war command run tests before packaging?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

Does grails war command run tests before packaging? I have a few tests that fail when I run test-app command but the grails war command successfully builds war even if tests fail.

Comment: The title is "grails war command does not run tests" and the question is "Does grails war command run tests before packaging?".  The title answers the question, correctly.

Comment: thanks for pointing out :). the title was messed up.

Answer (score 3):

> Does grails war command run tests before packaging?

No.

Comment: That's a clever way of getting around the minimum answer length rule

Comment: I didn't even know there was a minimum answer length rule. I guess I accidentally got around it.  I tend to include quotes if I think it is likely that the original text will be changed in a way that makes the answer less clear.

Comment: As an example, the title was originally "grails war command does not run tests" but has since been changed to "Does grails war command run tests before packaging?".  The title originally made a claim and then the description posed a question which was answered (correctly) by the claim.  After I answered "No" to the question I thought it not unlikely that the question might be changed to something like "Is there a way to make the war task run tests" or "Why doesn't the war task run tests" or something else for which the answer "No" would  no longer make sense.

Comment: Thanks guys I have a follow up question on this. I will ask in a different thread.